# Why this tsql query doesn't select what it intended to?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
declare @customerID int
set @customerID=1


;with cteDates as
(
  select dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, getdate()), 0) as [Date]
  union all
  select dateadd(hh, -1, [Date]) as [Date]
  from cteDates
  where [Date] > dateadd(hh, -23, getdate())
)
select
    sum(coalesce(field1,0)) field1,
    sum(coalesce(field2,0)) field2,
    sum(coalesce(field3,0)) field3,
    sum(coalesce(field4,0)) field4,
    sum(coalesce(field5,0)) field5,
    d.[Date]
from cteDates as d left join [Statistics] s
on d.Date=s.date
where s.customerID=@customerID and s.date>dateadd(hh,-24,getdate())
group by d.Date
```

I want to get hourly statistics for certain customer, if there is no value i want to select 0 anyway...

This query selects only rows which exists in Statistics table even though i have left join with calender CTE...

thanks, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are refering to statistics table in your where clause.

Try:

```
declare @customerID int
set @customerID=1

;with cteDates as
(
select dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, getdate()), 0) as [Date]
union all
select dateadd(hh, -1, [Date]) as [Date]
from cteDates
where [Date] > dateadd(hh, -23, getdate())
)
select
sum(coalesce(field1,0)) field1,
sum(coalesce(field2,0)) field2,
sum(coalesce(field3,0)) field3,
sum(coalesce(field4,0)) field4,
sum(coalesce(field5,0)) field5,
d.[Date]
from cteDates as d left join [Statistics] s
on d.Date=s.date
and s.customerID=@customerID and s.date>dateadd(hh,-24,getdate())
group by d.Date
```